# jQuery .ajax() with jsonp not invoking success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I have a facebook iframe application that makes a cross domain request to my server and requests data in JSONP format. This is my client side code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '***',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    method: 'set_user_prizes'
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: false,
                jsonpCallbackString: 'callback123',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log('success_function');
                    console.log(data);
                }
});
```

The problem is my success callback method isn't being invoked and I'm not sure why. Using Firebug I can see my server's response:

```
callback123({"success":true,"associated_prizes":[{"prizes_id":"6"},{"prizes_id":"1"}]})
```

Comment: Why are you passing `jsonp: false`?

Comment: @Slaks, I'm using codeigniter with my project. Codeigniter destroys GET data, so therefore I can't use the "&callback=" segment of the url if jquery appends it

Comment: @Dmitriy Naumov, no I am making a cross-domain request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the word `String` from the callback key as is illustrated in the following transformation. The value needs to remain a string.

Change:

```
jsonpCallbackString: 'callback123',
```

to

```
jsonpCallback: 'callback123',
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. The documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ says that the only valid values for jsonpCallback are either a string, or a function that returns a string which is the method to invoke.

Comment: I think this is partially correct.  You're looking for jsonpCallback: 'callback123'.  Remove the word "string", but keep the value as a string

Comment: @Mike Ruhlin, you were correct - this solved my problems. thank you!

Comment: Another solution that achieves the same thing is to add "?callback=?" to your URL. jQuery will generate a random callback function name to use internally and the ajax success event will get fired.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is

```
jsonpCallback: 'callback123'
```